# NAO error: No module named yaml

Tags: ros, yaml, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I am trying to make ROS run on the NAO.  I have followed the wiki for [Nao-Cross-Compiling](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling), and I get everything to show up on the robot as stated in the wiki.  However, when I go to run roscore, just to see if it will work, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/media/external/ros/electric/ros/bin/roscore",
> line 34, in 
> from ros import roslaunch   File "/media/external/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/**init**.py",
> line 57, in **getattr**
> return **import**(name)   File "/media/external/ros/electric/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/**init**.py",
> line 43, in 
> import roslaunch.param_dump   File "/media/external/ros/electric/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/param_dump.py",
> line 43, in 
> import yaml ImportError: No module named yaml

The PYTHONPATH for my setup.sh file looks like this:

> PYTHONPATH=/media/external/python:/media/external/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src:$PYTHONPATH

The /media/external/python folder contains the yaml folder.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[edit] OS is Ubuntu 10.04 and nao sdk and toolchain are 1.10.44

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12862/nao-error:-no-module-named-yaml/) by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're likely missing the python-yaml package on your system. It's a core system dependency when installing from source [instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source#Setup)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on 2012-02-05**:
Whenever I run the setup: sudo apt-get install build-essential python-yaml cmake subversion wget python-setuptools mercurial git-core, it tells me that pyton-yamal is already the newest version